# Virtual Public IP address

Tags: azure, ip, virtual-machine, virtual-ip-address

Right now, i am working on setting a docker on azure. There i stumbled on **Static Virtual Public IP Address**. I read about it but i still have some doubts.

1. How is **Static Virtual Public IP Address** different from the **Static Public IP Address**?
2. If i give port access to that particular **Static Virtual Public IP Address**, will it work fine as in case of **Static Public IP Address**?

***Context***: I have to access the docker using a window client in a company environment where port access can be provided to a particular IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MSN Tutorial says:**

***Use of reserved IP***

You want to ensure that outbound traffic from Azure uses a predictable IP address. You may have your on-premises firewall configured to allow only traffic from specific IP addresses. By reserving an IP, you will know the source IP address and won’t have to update your firewall rules due to an IP change.

Conclusion: It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Azure has two deployment models: Classic and ARM (Azure Resource Manager) Note that ARM is the newer and recommended option. IP addresses work differently in these models so its a good idea understand these better specifically in the context of what you are looking for which are public static (or reserved) IPs :

1. [IP addresses in Classic](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-classic/) include VIP (Virtual IP) and ILPIP (Instance Level Public IP) which is what I believe you are referring to.
2. [IP addresses in ARM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm/) work differently.

Comment: I am working on the classic model and i have a company set up which requires me to have a static ip for the port access(ssh access). Now my question is even if i give vm a static virtual ip , will it suffice the need for port access?

Comment: The virtual IP address (VIP) is hosted on the Azure Load Balancer. Traffic can only pass through it to a vm on explicitly declared endpoints. The instance-level IP address can be attached to a VM. Traffic to it immediately reaches the VM unless blocked by a network security group or firewall rule. Either type of IP address can be static (or reserved).