# How do I set a public static IP address to a storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, vnet

I have an Azure storage account with a blob endpoint of: 'blobstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net'.  I want to choose a static IP Address, because some of my more zealous customers want to only allocate a known set of IP addresses through their firewall.  I have already provided them with the list of Azure IP ranges for my Azure region, but they don't want to allocate such broad ranges.

Also: 1

In Azure portal | Storage | Networking | Custom domain: it says "Configure a custom domain for accessing **blob** data in your Azure storage account, like www.contoso.com".

If that is possible could I allocate the custom domain a static IP address?

Is it really only blob specific, what about queue endpoints? I could configure my DNS with each endpoint having a new CNAME entry.

Also: 2

Azure portal | Add new resource "[Public IP Address](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryItemDetailsBladeNopdl/product%7E/%7B%22displayName%22%3A%22Public%20IP%20address%22%2C%22itemDisplayName%22%3A%22Public%20IP%20address%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22Microsoft.PublicIPAddress%22%2C%22bigId%22%3A%22Microsoft.PublicIPAddress%22%2C%22offerId%22%3A%22PublicIPAddress%22%2C%22publisherId%22%3A%22Microsoft%22%2C%22publisherDisplayName%22%3A%22Microsoft%22%2C%22summary%22%3A%22An%20IP%20address%20that%20can%20be%20used%20with%20virtual%20machines%20and%20load%20balancers.%22%2C%22longSummary%22%3A%22An%20IP%20address%20that%20can%20be%20used%20with%20virtual%20machines%20and%20load%20balancers.%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%3Cp%3EA%20public%20IP%20address%20is%20a%20dynamic%20or%20static%20IP%20address%20that%20you%20can%20assign%20to%20virtual%20machines%2C%20load%20balancers%2C%20and%20virtual%20network%20gateways%20to%20communicate%20with%20the%20Internet.%20Your%20public%20IP%20addresses%20are%20associated%20with%20your%20Azure%20subscription%2C%20and%20can%20be%20moved%20freely%20between%20Azure%20resources.%20The%20address%20of%20dynamic%20public%20IP%20address%20may%20change%20when%20dissociated%20and%20moved%20between%20resources%2C%20or%20when%20the%20associated%20resource%20is%20shutdown%20or%20deleted.%20You%20can%20use%20a%20static%20public%20IP%20address%20to%20ensure%20that%20the%20assigned%20address%20remains%20the%20same%2C%20even%20if%20the%20associated%20resource%20is%20shutdown%20or%20deleted.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EIn%20the%20Classic%20deployment%20model%2C%20a%20public%20IP%20address%20was%20named%20an%20instance-level%20public%20IP%20(ILPIP)%20address%20when%20assigned%20to%20a%20virtual%20machine%20or%20role%20instance%20directly%2C%20and%20a%20virtual%20IP%20address%20(VIP)%20when%20assigned%20to%20a%20cloud%20service.%20Furthermore%2C%20a%20reserved%20IP%20address%20could%20be%20associated%20to%20the%20VIP%20of%20a%20cloud%20service%20to%20ensure%20that%20the%20assigned%20address%20remained%20the%20same%20even%20if%20its%20virtual%20machines%20or%20deployments%20were%20stopped.%20These%20concepts%20have%20now%20been%20unified%20in%20the%20Resource%20Manager%20deployment%20model%20with%20the%20public%20IP%20address%20resource.%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%22isPrivate%22%3Afalse%2C%22hasPrivateOffer%22%3Afalse%2C%22isMacc%22%3Atrue%2C%22isPreview%22%3Afalse%2C%22isByol%22%3Afalse%2C%22isCSPEnabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22isCSPSelective%22%3Afalse%2C%22isThirdParty%22%3Afalse%2C%22isStopSell%22%3Afalse%2C%22isReseller%22%3Afalse%2C%22hasFreeTrials%22%3Afalse%2C%22marketingMaterial%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22version%22%3A%221.1.5%22%2C%22metadata%22%3A%7B%22leadGeneration%22%3Anull%2C%22testDrive%22%3Anull%7D%2C%22categoryIds%22%3A%5B%22networking%22%5D%2C%22screenshotUris%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22links%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%220%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Service%20overview%22%2C%22uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Fvirtual-network-public-ip-address%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Pricing%20details%22%2C%22uri%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fazure.microsoft.com%2Fpricing%2Fdetails%2Fip-addresses%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22filters%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22plans%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22PublicIPAddress-ARM%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Public%20IP%20address%22%2C%22summary%22%3A%22An%20IP%20address%20that%20can%20be%20used%20with%20virtual%20machines%20and%20load%20balancers.%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%3Cp%3EA%20public%20IP%20address%20is%20a%20dynamic%20or%20static%20IP%20address%20that%20you%20can%20assign%20to%20virtual%20machines%2C%20load%20balancers%2C%20and%20virtual%20network%20gateways%20to%20communicate%20with%20the%20Internet.%20Your%20public%20IP%20addresses%20are%20associated%20with%20your%20Azure%20subscription%2C%20and%20can%20be%20moved%20freely%20between%20Azure%20resources.%20The%20address%20of%20dynamic%20public%20IP%20address%20may%20change%20when%20dissociated%20and%20moved%20between%20resources%2C%20or%20when%20the%20associated%20resource%20is%20shutdown%20or%20deleted.%20You%20can%20use%20a%20static%20public%20IP%20address%20to%20ensure%20that%20the%20assigned%20address%20remains%20the%20same%2C%20even%20if%20the%20associated%20resource%20is%20shutdown%20or%20deleted.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EIn%20the%20Classic%20deployment%20model%2C%20a%20public%20IP%20address%20was%20named%20an%20instance-level%20public%20IP%20(ILPIP)%20address%20when%20assigned%20to%20a%20virtual%20machine%20or%20role%20instance%20directly%2C%20and%20a%20virtual%20IP%20address%20(VIP)%20when%20assigned%20to%20a%20cloud%20service.%20Furthermore%2C%20a%20reserved%20IP%20address%20could%20be%20associated%20to%20the%20VIP%20of%20a%20cloud%20service%20to%20ensure%20that%20the%20assigned%20address%20remained%20the%20same%20even%20if%20its%20virtual%20machines%20or%20deployments%20were%20stopped.%20These%20concepts%20have%20now%20been%20unified%20in%20the%20Resource%20Manager%20deployment%20model%20with%20the%20public%20IP%20address%20resource.%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%22restrictedAudience%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22skuId%22%3A%22PublicIPAddress-ARM%22%2C%22planId%22%3A%22PublicIPAddress-ARM%22%2C%22legacyPlanId%22%3A%22Microsoft.PublicIPAddress-ARM%22%2C%22keywords%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22type%22%3A%22None%22%2C%22leadGeneration%22%3Anull%2C%22testDrive%22%3Anull%2C%22categoryIds%22%3A%5B%22networking%22%5D%2C%22conversionPaths%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22metadata%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22uiDefinitionUri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcatalogartifact.azureedge.net%2Fpublicartifacts%2FMicrosoft.PublicIPAddress-ARM-1.1.5%2FUIDefinition.json%22%2C%22artifacts%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22PublicIPAddress%22%2C%22uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcatalogartifact.azureedge.net%2Fpublicartifacts%2FMicrosoft.PublicIPAddress-ARM-1.1.5%2FPublicIPAddress.json%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22Template%22%7D%5D%2C%22version%22%3A%221.1.5%22%2C%22itemName%22%3A%22PublicIPAddress-ARM%22%2C%22isPrivate%22%3Afalse%2C%22isHidden%22%3Afalse%2C%22hasFreeTrials%22%3Afalse%2C%22isByol%22%3Afalse%2C%22isFree%22%3Afalse%2C%22isPayg%22%3Afalse%2C%22isStopSell%22%3Afalse%2C%22cspState%22%3A%22OptIn%22%2C%22isQuantifiable%22%3Afalse%2C%22purchaseDurationDiscounts%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22upns%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22hasRI%22%3Afalse%2C%22stackType%22%3A%22ARM%22%7D%5D%2C%22selectedPlanId%22%3A%22PublicIPAddress-ARM%22%2C%22iconFileUris%22%3A%7B%22small%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcatalogartifact.azureedge.net%2Fpublicartifacts%2FMicrosoft.PublicIPAddress-ARM-1.1.5%2FSmall.png%22%2C%22medium%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcatalogartifact.azureedge.net%2Fpublicartifacts%2FMicrosoft.PublicIPAddress-ARM-1.1.5%2FMedium.png%22%2C%22large%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcatalogartifact.azureedge.net%2Fpublicartifacts%2FMicrosoft.PublicIPAddress-ARM-1.1.5%2FLarge.png%22%2C%22wide%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcatalogartifact.azureedge.net%2Fpublicartifacts%2FMicrosoft.PublicIPAddress-ARM-1.1.5%2FWide.png%22%7D%2C%22itemType%22%3A%22Single%22%2C%22hasNoProducts%22%3Atrue%2C%22hasNoPlans%22%3Afalse%2C%22privateBadgeText%22%3Anull%2C%22createBladeType%22%3A1%2C%22offerType%22%3A%22None%22%2C%22useEnterpriseContract%22%3Afalse%2C%22hasStandardContractAmendments%22%3Afalse%2C%22standardContractAmendmentsRevisionId%22%3A%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%22%2C%22supportUri%22%3Anull%2C%22galleryItemAccess%22%3A0%2C%22privateSubscriptions%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22isTenantPrivate%22%3Afalse%2C%22hasRIPlans%22%3Afalse%7D/id/PublicIPAddress-ARM/resourceGroupId//resourceGroupLocation//dontDiscardJourney%7E/false)", allows me to add a public statis IP address for a virtual network gateway (VNG?). I know it's possible to apply a static IP to a VM.  How does one create or configure a VNG? or Azure VNet? to apply a static IP to a Storage endpoint?

I read these, but they were not helpful:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/b7dbea96-5349-45c6-8774-f8c766d08e31/help-assign-static-ip-to-a-blob-storage-account?forum=windowsazuredata
[Virtual Public IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979724/virtual-public-ip-address)

Also posted on the [Azure Docs Questions forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/872688/how-to-allocate-azure-storage-a-static-public-ip-a.html)

Comment: how to docs on new Virtual Network Gateway and vNet are found via Google on Technet.  Static IP, with a quick Google i found a company that supports that.  I don't work nor get paid by that company, but just showing you that these questions have widely been answered.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022, Azure Storage service does not support public IPs, but Azure API management does.

Configuring APIm service with a public static IP, then create a 'pass through' endpoint for each storage type.

Each client's app.config needs "AzureWebJobsStorage" updated to send requests through an API Management route for each endpoint type. I am currently using a generic connection not specifying the endpoints, so each client will need updating to use the '[explicit storage endpoint connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-for-an-explicit-storage-endpoint)

Alternative to APIm: investigate dotnet YARP as a reverse proxy hosted on an Azure WebApp and manage re-routing that way.

Comment: I wish this answer had a bit more detail for someone getting acquainted with these Azure features like myself. For example, walk-through would be great!